# Sort struct vector as sub-groups

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, vector

I have a struct vector looks like this:

```
struct table{

int k;
int r;
int c;

}

std::vector<table> myvector;
```

I want to sort the vector's object based on the following criteria:

- Object with same `r` value should be placed together (I called the accumulation of the same `r` as a "group").
- The objects inside same group should be in ascending sequence based on the `c` value.
- The groups should be sorted in ascending sequence based on the first object's `c` value.

For instance, if `myvector` is like this (each column represents a object):

```
k:  1   2   3   5   4   6
r:  3   3   3   2   3   2
c:  3   4   2   3   1   4
```

After sorting the vector should be like this:

```
k:  4   3   1   2   5   6
r:  3   3   3   3   2   2
c:  1   2   3   4   3   4
```

My solution is that first sort the vector base on `r` value so that we put the same `r` value together:

```
std::sort(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), compare_r);

bool compare_r(table left, table right){return left.r < right.r;}
```

The we sort inside each group:

```
bool compare_c(table left, table right){return left.c < right.c;}

std::vector<table>::iterator it1, it2;
it1 = myvector.begin();
it2 = it1;

int r_now = it1 -> r;

for(; it2 != myvector.end(); ++it2){

    if(it2 -> r != r_now){
        std::sort(it1, it2, compare_c);
        r_now = it2 -> r;
        it1 = it2;
    }

}

std::sort(it1, it2, compare_c);
```

Right now `myvector` becomes:

```
k:  5   6   4   3   1   2   
r:  2   2   3   3   3   3   
c:  3   4   1   2   3   4
```

The final step is to put objects with k = 5 & 6 to the back of the vector because 1st group's 1st c = 3 is larger than the 1st c = 1 of the 2nd group (third criteria). I can copy k = 5 & 6 and erase them, then insert them at the end of `myvector`. But that seems like not very efficient. Does anyone has a better idea?

Comment: Here's one idea. Sort on `c` first. Then pass over the vector and compute the rank of each `r` - basically, the index where a particular value of `r` occurs first; you could store it in `std::map<int, int>`, say. Then use `std::stable_sort` to sort on rank of `r` (stable sort to preserve the ordering on `c`)

Comment: The relation between `k`,`r` and `c` is unclear.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik great idea, just probably `std::unordered_map` should be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is possible implementation of idea suggested by @IgorTandetnik:

```
std::vector<table> myvector;
// sort based by c
std::sort( myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), []( const auto &l, const auto &r ) {
     return l.c < r.c;
} );
std::unordered_map<int,int> ranks;
// populate ranks based on smallest (first) c
std::transform( myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), std::inserter( ranks ), []( const auto &t ) { return std::make_pair( t.r, t.c ); } );
// stable sort by ranks of r
std::stable_sort( myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), [&ranks]( const auto &l, const auto &r ) {
     return ranks[l.r] < ranks[r.r];
} );
```

I did not try to compile the code, as you did not provide MCVE, but it should work after fixing syntax errors if any.

Comment: Thank you! I think it is a brilliant approach. By the way, the unordered_map should include not just the smallest `c`, but all the first` c` where an `r` first appears.

Comment: @ShiqiHe because at the time map is populated vector is already sortered in ascending order by `c` naturally map will be populated with all `r`  and smallest `c` were it first appeared.